# Creating git submodule without a remote

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository, git-subrepo

I want to have a `sub` repo inside my `main` repo which can push and pull from a completely different remote repo than my `main`. So I want a submodule. But I want to create the submodule locally, then push it to remote. It does not exist anywhere yet.

All the of the examples I have seen involve pulling a remote repo into a submodule, to the degree that this is how submodules are created to begin with

```
git submodule add git@github.com:url_to/awesome_submodule.git path_to_awesome_submodule
```

Is there any way to create the submodule, make some commits, then push them to the remote repo in question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Creating git submodule without a remote

No: your submodule must have a remote repo from which it is cloned.

In your case, make sure the root folder of your sub-repo is not tracked:

```
git rm sub
```

Then move/delete it, and add it back as a submodule repo:

```
cd main
git submodule add git@github.com:url_to/awesome_submodule.git sub
```

From there, you can go in that submodule and:

- checkout a branch (by default, you are in detached HEAD)
- make some commit
- push from it to its own remote URL.